# Detailed proof on the limit expression of natural logarithm

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I want to know the derivation of the following identity:

$$
\ln({x}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n(x^{1/n} - 1)
$$

I've checked this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282339/logarithm-as-limit) for answers but I'm having a hard time grasping the explanations. Especially

"*$\ln({z})$ is the derivative of $t\mapsto z^t$ at  $t=0$*"

Can anyone explain it clearly to me?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you define the symbol $\ln x$? Answer to your question depends on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(x)}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}=\left.\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d y}\right|_{y=0}e^{y\ln(x)}=\ln(x).$$