# Evaluate $\large \int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\ln x} + \frac{1}{1-x}\right)^2 \mathrm dx $ using elementary, high school techniques

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $\large \int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\ln x} + \frac{1}{1-x}\right)^2 \mathrm dx $
$$$$
I was given this integral by a friend who saw this here on MSE. He asked me if I could solve it using the very basic tools I have. I was of course unsuccessful.$$$$

My short and unsuccessful attempt:
$$\large \int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\ln x} + \frac{1}{1-x}\right)^2 \mathrm dx $$

$$\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{(\ln x)^2} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} +\frac{2}{\ln x(1-x)}\right) \mathrm dx $$
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{(\ln x)^2}+\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+\int_0^1\frac{2}{\ln x(1-x)}$$

The problem (apart from the fact that I don't know as yet how to attempt the third integral) is that the second integral (I think) diverges.

Could somebody please help me solve it using preferably only these: Integration by Parts, Integration by Substitution, Partial Fraction Decomposition or Differentiating under the Integral Sign?$$$$
Thanks so much in advance, and I'm truly sorry for the trouble I have caused.

Comment: If this would help, the question already exists [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281406/evaluate-int-01-left-frac1-ln-x-frac11-x-right2-mathrm-dx).

Comment: I know of no normal, standard high school that includes these things in its curriculum. Perhaps some high school for very gifted students...

Comment: One thing for sure:  splitting into three definite integrals won't work, since each of the three, evaluated by itself, diverges.

Comment: Sir, what would you suggest then?

Comment: @jack is  this really a duplicate? going over the old topic there is nothing even close to high-school maths. so if someone would find something which fits this requirement it would be really "new"

Comment: @tired: I really doubt this problem can be solved through something more elementary than the robjohn's approach in the other question. Even if I am wrong, I think it is best to add another solution to the other thread, just to keep things tidy.

Comment: @jack ok, you're right!